# How to unfold a Compressed bitmap data sent by android to a Python flask based API

Tags: python, android, flask, bitmap, android-volley

I am sending a bitmap (after creating a rescaled bitmap of fixed size of 750x900) after compression to a flask based API.

```
    public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
            
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
          byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
          String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
          return temp;
        }
```

A bitmap of total of 750x900x4 (RGBA channel too)(=2700000) bytes after compression gets serialized into 698003 bytes. But I don't understand how to get RGB values in PYTHON of each after this compression?

I got the de-serialized array back (of same size of 698003 bytes) but what to do with it to get my image back?

The number of bytes after compression is neither a multiple of 4 or 3 (if alpha channel is removed)

Please help, Thanks in advance!